# Spring batch restrict single instance of job across multiple servers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have one Spring Batch job that can potentially be run across multiple servers. I have a listener in place that prevents multiple instances of the job being run at the same time on one server. However, I want to ensure this job can't be run at the same time on multiple servers.

I've searched and found no solution to this problem

Comment: Are you sharing the same job repository datastore across the servers?  If so, Spring Batch shouldn't let you launch more than one JobExecution (same job name and same parameters) at the same time.  That being said, you can also use the distributed lock mechanism that is included in Spring Integration (we use it in Spring Cloud Task for that very use case).

Comment: @MichaelMinella I am sharing the same job repository datastore across the servers, except I have a job increment count in place as a param, so the job runs with the same name but different parameters. I've been looking at the distributed lock mechanism but can't seem to find good info on it. I'll keep searching

Comment: Here is what we did for Spring Cloud Task.  Applying this same mechanism around your batch launching logic would work the same way: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/task/configuration/SingleInstanceTaskListener.java

Comment: @MichaelMinella Thank you very much - I'm going to try and get this implemented

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I implemented a listener that checks the number of running Job Executions within the spring batch control tables matching a certain name. If there size of the executions exceeds 1, jobExecution of the current job fails. Here's the code:

```
@Component
public class SingleInstanceListener implements JobExecutionListener {
    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer explorer;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        String jobName = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName();
        Set<JobExecution> executions = explorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
        if(executions.size() > 1) {
            jobExecution.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {

    }

}
```

Comment: it's worth noting, that if the batch persistence store is a database, then a single execution in an 'UNKNOWN' state will then prevent the batch from executing again. It's worth testing the executions for a time limit, or using custom cleanup code to remove poison 'UNKNOWN' executions.

Comment: Im getting org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobExecutionNotRunningException: JobExecution must be running so that it can be stopped what is obvious as wa are trying to stop job in beforeJob method