# How to restrict multiple instances of spring batch job running?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

My Spring batch is triggered by a Rest end point. I am looking for the solution to run only one instance of a job at a time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch restrict single instance of job across multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50746527/spring-batch-restrict-single-instance-of-job-across-multiple-servers)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a listener overriding beforeJob method, that will run before the job starts and check if another instance of the same job is running. If another instance is already running, it will stop the current run.

```
@Component
public class MultipleCheckListener implements JobExecutionListener {
    @Autowired
    private JobExplorer explorer;

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        String jobName = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName();
        Set<JobExecution> executions = explorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
        if(executions.size() > 1) {
            jobExecution.stop();
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to stop the execution and use the above listener**

```
@Bean
public Job JobSE(JobRepository jobRepository, JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener)
    throws UnexpectedInputException, ParseException {
    return new JobBuilder(CUSTOMER_REPORT_JOB_SE, jobRepository)
        .start((Step) applicationContext.getBean("jobSEStep"))
        .preventRestart()
        .listener(jobExecutionListener)
        .build();
}
@Bean
public JobExecutionListener jobExecutionListener(JobExplorer explorer, JobOperator jobOperator) {
    return new JobExecutionListener() {
        @Override
        public void beforeJob(@NonNull JobExecution jobExecution) {
            String jobName = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName();
            Set<JobExecution> executions = explorer.findRunningJobExecutions(jobName);
            if (executions.size() > 1) {
                try {
                    jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getId());
                    jobExecution.setStatus(BatchStatus.STOPPED);
                } catch (NoSuchJobExecutionException | JobExecutionNotRunningException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```